# RoR Integration Integration Test, how to fix the RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I have the next integration text, to create a new Category but for some reason I can't make the correct redirect.

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "get new category form and create category" do
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
        post categories_path, params: { category: { name: "measure tension" } }
        follow_redirect!
    end
    assert_template 'categories/index'
    assert_match "measure tension", response.body
  end

end
```

The error is:

```
Error:
CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category:
RuntimeError: not a redirect! 200 OK
     test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CreateCategoriesTest>'
    test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:CreateCategoriesTest>'


bin/rails test test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:5
```

I don't know if I have to change someting in the controller. But to better understanding there is the code:

```
def create
 @category = Category.new(category_params)
 if @category.save
   flash[:success] = "Category was created successfully"
   redirect_to categories_path
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing one the validations failed so that the record is not being saved. Use pry or byebug to set a breakpoint after `@category = Category.new(category_params)` and run `@category.valid?` and `@category.errors` to check whats wrong.

Comment: Yes. In fact I was forgetting a parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCategoriesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

 test "get new category form and create category" do
  get new_category_path
  assert_template 'categories/new'
  assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
    post categories_path, params: { category: { name: "measure tension", description: "this is the description" } }
    follow_redirect!
  end
  assert_template 'categories/index'
  assert_match "measure tension", response.body
 end

end
```